# Screen Lock pauses/halts terminal until unlock

Tags: command-line, lock-screen

When I lock my screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> all terminal jobs pause until the screen is unlocked again, but I want them to run in the background instead (e.g. when compiling).

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure? How did you determine that terminal jobs were paused? Does the same happen if you minimize the terminal emulator window before you lock the session using this keyboard shortcut?

Comment: What terminal emulator? Does the same happen in other terminal emulators too?

Comment: i use the zsh shell and konsole, didnt test with minimze console window before locking ( yet ).

Comment: @David Yes im sure ), atleast on Xubuntu 17.10

Comment: Could you please try to minimise the terminal emulator window before you lock the session using Ctrl+Shift+L? I suspect that the TE intercepts parts of this shortcut and interprets it as a command to pause all running jobs.

Answer (score 1):

It is weird if locking your screen pauses your scripts, it is not supposed to do that. 
You can try to use detached terminals like [tmux](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tmux) or [screen](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/screen) to be sure that your command will not stop